# Can add active class, but can't seem to remove it with next click function

Tags: jquery

Evening all. Trying to doctor a script written to show/hide markers for a Google Map. Problem is that I need to add an active class to each click function, but then remove it when the next on click event occurs.  I've tried every combination under the sun, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".category-header").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        showCategory($(this).text(), $(this).parent().addClass("active").attr("zoom"));
    })
  })
  $(".map-item").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        getMarker($(this).text(), $(this).addClass("active").attr('zoom'));
    })
  })
})

function showCategory(category, zoom) {
  category = String(category).toLowerCase();
  infowindow.close();
  $(".map-items-container").not($("#" + category + "-container .map-items-container")).slideUp();
  target = $(".map-category").has('.category-header:contains("' + category + '")');
  target.find($(".map-items-container")).slideDown();   
  var LatLngList = new Array (homemarker.getPosition());    
  for (var i=0; i<allMarkers.length; i++) {
    if (allMarkers[i].category == category) {
        allMarkers[i].setVisible(true);
        LatLngList.push(allMarkers[i].getPosition());
    } else {
        allMarkers[i].setVisible(false);
    }
  }
```

And the HTML:

```
    <div id="community-map-container">

<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<div id="map-container">
    <div id="map-container-content">

        <div id="restaurants-container" class="map-category">
            <h2><span class="category-header">restaurants</span> & Cafes</h2>
            <div class="map-items-container">
                <div class="map-item" category="restaurants" lng="-123.368063" lat="48.424835">Bard & Banker</div>
            </div><!-- map-items-container -->
        </div><!-- category -->

        <div id="everyday-container" class="map-category">
            <h2><span class="category-header">everyday</span> needs</h2>
            <div class="map-items-container">
                <div class="map-item" category="everyday" lng="-123.366734" lat="48.427385">Fish Hair Salon</div>
            </div><!-- map-items-container -->
        </div><!-- category -->

        <div id="recreation-container" class="map-category">
            <h2 class="category-header">recreation</h2>
            <div class="map-items-container">
            </div><!-- map-items-container -->
        </div><!-- category -->

        <div id="shopping-container" class="map-category">
            <h2 class="category-header">shopping</h2>
            <div class="map-items-container">
                <div class="map-item" category="shopping" lng="-123.368261" lat="48.427693">American Apparel</div>
            </div><!-- map-items-container -->
        </div><!-- category -->

    </div><!-- map-container-content -->
</div><!-- map-container -->

    </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. For the record, I've tried toggleClass and removeClass but can't seem to get it working consistently with this script.

Comment: You don't need to use .each() just bind the click on the elements directly

Comment: I thought as much, but would that make it so that I can just add the removeClass before the addClass?

Comment: What is the element that has the "zoom" attribute? When using addClass, you can also use removeClass.

Comment: Btw. attr("zoom") is not valid here. Create a data-zoom attribute.

Comment: The zoom is for adding an attribute to the selector for the Google Map that accompanies the code. I refer to the fact that it has to do with Google Maps in my description. If it can use data-zoom, I was unaware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `.each()` like Anton said in the comments.

Then I added appropriate `removeClass("active")` to all of the elements that could have the class active but should not anymore.

```
$(".category-header").click(function() {
    $(".category-header").parents().removeClass("active");
    showCategory($(this).text(), $(this).parent().addClass("active").attr("zoom"));
})


$(".map-item").click(function() {
    $(".map-item").removeClass("active");
    getMarker($(this).text(), $(this).addClass("active").attr('zoom'));
})
```

Comment: Would it be weird if I said I loved you right now? Lol. That took me way too long to figure out but apparently two seconds for all you pros. Thank you so much! It won't let me accept this answer yet because you're too fast, but I will in a second. Thanks!